# How to go to previous page in windows phone 8 when back button is pressed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a home page or landing page in my windows phone c# based app where user enters login details and upon successful login user is redirected to page2 . Here the user will see a list box with few items . Upon selecting an item from this list box a new page called "Threadx" opens.(where x is the each page that opens upon clicking the x item in the list box)

While user is on this Thread page "Threadx" he may receive the toast notifications and the thread gets updated with new replies or answers on that thread.

But When user clicks on back button the "ThreadX" page doesn't get closed and instead it goes to its previous state where it has less number of messages , and so on until the app gets closed.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I would like to know if this "Threadx" page can be closed upon clicking back button without affecting other "Threadx+1","Threadx+2"..."Threadx+n" pages.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: That's not normally how the back button should work and while you might be able to do what you want, your app may fail validation.

Comment: @Peter When I click on back button the page "ThreadX" is retained until the page goes back to its initial state of the messages . If I would have received 3 messages after the "ThreadX" page is opened I had to click on back button 3 times being in the same page. Can this be avoided ?

Comment: Normally it's avoided by not bringing up a "page" (e.g. something more like a dialog instead of a URL) so that *back* goes back to the last page and skips the non-page-like UI in dialogs...

Comment: @PeterRitchie but that's how chat applications work. In a chat window you can receive multiple messages being in the same page and still you would be able to go back to any previous page by clicking back button.

Comment: So, when you press the back button on a ThreadX page, do you want to always go to the page with the list of threads, or do you want to go to the previous ThreadX page (which is for another thread) if such page exists?

Comment: @yasen the page where the list of threads are there .

Comment: In the code that you posted, can't you just replace `return;` with `this.Frame.GoBack();` or `this.NavigationService.GoBack();`? Wouldn't this do just what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally windows keeps the pages on it's stack when you leave a page and navigate to another page. If you want to navigate to the previous page on pressing the Back Button you can do following things:

Add following line to `OnNavigatedTo` method:

```
Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

Add definition for  `HardwareButtons_BackPressed` method:

```
    private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            Frame.GoBack();
    }
```

Don't forget to add `Windows.Phone.UI.Input` to the namespace list.

Answer (score -1):

The other way I got it worked was using the below code in the onnavigateto method in my "thread" page and it worked for me. Let me know if there is an elegant way of doing it or better way of doing it .

```
if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
         {
             NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
         }
```

Comment: This seems wrong... What happens when you press the Back button on Page2 when you are navigated to Page2 by this code? Also, when the user gets updates on any "ThreadX" page, what exactly do you do? Do you navigate to a new "ThreadX" page?

Comment: When i press the back button on Page2 i go back to the Main page where login happens.

Comment: This cannot be used to navigate backward using back button.